# RxJS: Asynchronously mutate tree

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, reactive-programming, rxjs

I have a sequence of objects that I need to asynchronously modify by adding a property to each object:

```
[{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }] => [{ id: 1, foo: 'bar' }, { id: 2, foo: 'bar' }]
```

The synchronous equivalent of this would be:

```
var xs = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }];
// Warning: mutation!
xs.forEach(function (x) {
    x.foo = 'bar';
});

var newXs = xs;
```

However, in my case I need to append the `foo` property asynchronously. I would like the end value to be a sequence of objects with the `foo` property added.

I came up with the following code to solve this problem. In this example I'm just adding a property to each object with a value of `bar`.

```
var xs = Rx.Observable.fromArray([{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }]);
var propertyValues = xs
    // Warning: mutation!
    .flatMap(function (x) {
        return Rx.Observable.return('bar');
    });

var newXs =
    .zip(propertyValues, function (x, propertyValue) {
        // Append the property here
        x.foo = propertyValue;
        return x;
    })
    .toArray();

newXs.subscribe(function (y) { console.log(y); });
```

Is this the best way to solve my problem, or does Rx provide a better means for asynchronously mutating objects in a sequence? I'm looking for a cleaner solution because I have a deep tree that I need to mutate, and this code quickly becomes unweidly:

```
var xs = Rx.Observable.fromArray([{ id: 1, blocks: [ {} ] }, { id: 2, blocks: [ {} ] } ]);
var propertyValues = xs
    // Warning: mutation!
    .flatMap(function (x) {
        return Rx.Observable.fromArray(x.blocks)
            .flatMap(function (block) {
                var blockS = Rx.Observable.return(block);

                var propertyValues = blockS.flatMap(function (block) {
                    return Rx.Observable.return('bar');
                });

                return blockS.zip(propertyValues, function (block, propertyValue) {
                    block.foo = propertyValue;
                    return block;
                });
            })
            .toArray();
    });

xs
    .zip(propertyValues, function (x, propertyValue) {
        // Rewrite the property here
        x.blocks = propertyValue;
        return x;
    })
    .toArray()
    .subscribe(function (newXs) { console.log(newXs); });
```

Perhaps I shouldn't be performing this mutation in the first place?

Comment: When you say you have a "deep tree", I assume you have a recursive data structure, yes? Would it be enough to just use a recursive function then, and parameterize any variations that occur between levels?

Comment: In both cases you've created `propertyValues` as a stream. Is there a reason for that? If not, I'd instead be recommending that you just return the augmented object from a `map` operation.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you need to create two separate Observables: one for the list you're updating and one for the resulting value?

If you simply perform a .map() over your original list, you should be able to asynchronously update the list and subscribe to the result:

```
// This is the function that generates the new property value
function getBlocks(x) { ... }

const updatedList$ = Rx.Observable.fromArray(originalList)
    // What we're essentially doing here is scheduling work
    // to be completed for each item
    .map(x => Object.assign({}, x, { blocks: getBlocks(x)}))
    .toArray();

// Finally we can wait for our updatedList$ observable to emit
// the modified list
updatedList$.subscribe(list => console.log(list));
```

To abstract this functionality, I created a helper function that will explicitly schedule work to occur for each item using setTimeout:

```
function asyncMap(xs, fn) {
    return Rx.Observable.fromArray(xs)
        .flatMap(x => {
            return new Rx.Observable.create(observer => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    observer.onNext(fn(x));
                    observer.completed();
                }, 0);
            });
        })
        .toArray();
}
```

You can use this function to schedule work to be completed for each item:

```
function updateItem(x) {
    return Object.assign({}, x, { blocks: getBlocks(x) }
}

var updatedList$ = asyncMap(originalList, updateItem);
updateList$.subscribe(newList => console.log(newList));
```